# Знаки препинания в эпитафии

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите расставить знаки препинания в эпитафии:

**Все в прошлое ушло и не вернешь

Лишь в памяти остался не забыть

И рядом с нами нет тебя но все ж

В наших сердцах ты продолжаешь жить**

Comment: Чтобы соблюсти размер не меняя смысл, четвертую строчку можно сделать такой: "У нас в сердцах ты продолжаешь жить".

Answer (score 2):

При прочтении эпитафии, предложенной Вами к рассмотрению, у меня возникли ассоциации со стихотворением Николая Асеева:

*Я не могу без тебя жить!

Мне и в дожди без тебя — сушь,

Мне и в жару без тебя — стыть.

Мне без тебя и Москва — глушь.*

*Мне без тебя каждый час — с год;

Если бы время мельчить, дробя!

Мне даже синий небесный свод

Кажется каменным без тебя.*

*Я ничего не хочу знать —

Бедность друзей, верность врагов,

Я ничего не хочу ждать.

Кроме твоих драгоценных шагов.*

Мои пунктационные предложения будут такими:

***Все в прошлое ушло — и не вернешь,

Лишь в памяти остался — не забыть!

И рядом с нами нет тебя, но все ж

В родных сердцах ты продолжаешь жить...***

Солидарна с Ариной в том, что последнюю строчку необходимо подкорректировать.

Comment: Я сначала тоже хотела поставить тире в первой строке, но потом подумала, что два тире - это уже перебор. А Вы как думаете?

Comment: Если бы четверостишие не было эпитафией, я бы в первой строке и восклицательный знак поставила. Но! - насколько сильны человеческие переживания от утраты, настолько каждый -чаще всего - хочет их скрыть от посторонних. ЭТО - только моё, эти чувства принадлежат только мне, я даже болью по любимому не хочу ни с кем делиться!

Comment: @Arina Есть достаточно эпитафий с двумя(тремя) тире и двоеточиями: Ты нес нам свет — волшебный, добрый, Твой мир был сказочно красив. Тебя — единственного — помним, За твой талант благодарим. / Жизнь, как танец, как полёт В вихре света и движенья. Верю: смерть — лишь переход. Знаю: будет продолженье. / Как рождаемся — не помним, как умрем — не знаем (эпитафия по мотивам цитаты А.Солженицына: «Две загадки в мире есть: как родился — не помню, как умру — не знаю»).

Comment: А данном случае я имею в виду не грамматику, а художественную выразительность текста. Когда мы ставим два тире, то их эмоциональное воздействие как бы делится пополам. Мне же кажется, что  эмоциональным центром должно быть иеннно  второе тире.

Answer (score 1):

Все в прошлое ушло, и не вернешь,
Лишь в памяти остался  – не забыть!
И рядом с нами нет тебя,  но все ж
В  сердцах родных ты продолжаешь жить.

Последняя строка немного отредактирована с соответствии с размером стиха.